# Getting all row names that have same value for a specific column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row

Imagine I have this data frame df

```
    Amount    Class
A1    25        1
A2    40        1
B1    57        2
B2    23        2
B3    34        2
C4    45        3
C5    234       3
C1    23        3
```

What I want to do is get all row names that has the same value in the Class column. For example get all row names for Class value 2 would give me: B1, B2, B3

I tried using this:

```
rownames(df[df$Class==df$Class[3],])
```

This works when I want to get row names for Class value 1 but gives me the same result as when I type in 2 instead of one. What am I doing wrong or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The second element of `df$Class`, i.e. `df$Class[2]`, is 1. So it is going to give you the same result

Comment: Try `row.names(df)[df$Class == df$Class[3]]`   Advantage is that it  keeep it as a vector instead of a data.frame

Comment: `rownames(subset(df, Class == 2))`

Comment: rownames(subset(df, Class == 2)) works, thanks! I was overthinking...

Comment: Why not just `rownames(df)[df$Class == 2]` ?